# Javascript: difference between using an IIFE and a block statement

Tags: javascript, syntax, scope, block, iife

IIFE are mainly used to encapsulate scope

```
(function () {
    let myVar = 10; // not global
    // ...
}());
```

but why not just use a block statement?

```
{
    let myVar = 10; // also not global
    // ...
}
```

are there other benefits for using IIFE further than scope encapsulation?

Comment: Variable `myVar` is not global because of the keyword `let`.

Comment: Once an IIFE is completed anything within the closure that isn't returned is discarded, otherwise using a block statement whatever scope that the variables are contained within isn't necessarily removed and `myvar` could possibly be left in a larger scope that it isn't wanted or warranted to be available within.

Comment: Block scope is ES6+ feature, It doesn't work in old browser like IE. Also, only variables declared by const and let are block scoped. For var you need IIFE

Comment: A block doesn’t have a return value. IIFEs may be replaced by [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) in the future.

Comment: check out this post for a good explanation: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @zfrisch _“using a block statement whatever scope that the variables are contained within isn't necessarily removed”_ — do you have any sources on that? Why should that be true? Why would `myVar` become scoped to a surrounding scope if it is `let`-declared?

Comment: An IIFE written with `function` also potentially has a different `this` than a block statement. There are likely a whole lot of differences.

Comment: @Xufox I wasn't suggesting that it would be available from any scope above the one it is declared within, (`let` is block scoped so there wouldn't be any concern of it leaking to a higher scope) I was stating that on the whole it might be available in a scope that it wasn't desired to be within, and in the case of an uncareful coder it could lead to a syntax error wherein the variable( for instance `myvar` ) was already declared. This would most likely be in the case of a library. For instance it's why JQuery has an override if `$` as a window variable is already being used. .

Comment: @zfrisch Isn't that also true for a variable in an IIFE?

Comment: @Barmar Of course, but that doesn't affect the use of it. The benefit IIFE provides is an instantly returnable value or reference comprised of variables that can be named the same as any externally scoped variables without affecting them, and then are garbage collected immediately upon completion of the function.The blocked function isn't invoked immediately/ if it is named or global is a reference to a function and that function has to persist. To answer the OP's real question, no,  there is nothing outside of encapsulation that it offers, but it's what justifies its existence in the first.

Comment: I realize I may be confusing the issue with too many words. Apologies! The less wordy version is that an IIFE can immediately return something to the scope it was called within without polluting any higher scope or causing a syntax error for declaring the same variable more than once.

Comment: good point, post is as an answer

Comment: @zfrisch WRONG. Block statement does not pollute parent scope and can redeclare existing variables as well.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev read the rest of the comments. I already stated both those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block statements are a pretty recent feature. And yes, before they were introduced, IIFEs were used instead.

Nowadays I can think of at least one case, when IIFEs are irreplacable. Look at this:

```
(async () => { const foo = await someAsyncFunction() })()
```

See? The `await` keyword can only live in an `async` function, hence if your `await`-containing expression is not wrapped by any function, you have to wrap it by an async IIFE.

UPD: this answer is outdated, since top-level `await` is now available, so no need to use IIFE to wrap it, so there are even less uses for IIFEs now, if any.

Comment: I think the case with async is already handled by top-level await. It's just the same in JS today.

Comment: Top-level await is blocking, but the example in this answer isn't

Answer (score 2):

[IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) take advantage of function scope. Functions and variables declared with `var` are scoped within the parent function.

[Block statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) take advantage of block scope. Variables declared with `let` and `const` are scoped within the block.

Block statements don't encapsulate functions or variables declared with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you'll understand the concept better:

```
if(true){
 var something = 'something' // This is global now. Block scoping for var works fine inside function definition but not for **if statements** or similar ones
}

console.log(something)
```

Try changing **var** to **let** you won't be able to access **something** in the console.log statement.