# IIFE vs scope braces

Tags: javascript

Perhaps this is the stupidest question, but for [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), it mentions being used as a scope that would not pollute the global namespace.

Why would that be necessary as opposed to just using braces by itself to delimit scope (like in C)? For example:

```js
{
    let firstVariable = 1;
    let secondVariable = 2;
}
console.log(firstVariable);
```

Instead of:

```js
(function () {
    let firstVariable = 1;
    let secondVariable = 2;
})();
console.log(firstVariable);
```

Comment: Before let and const we only had var which is function scoped, not block scoped.

Comment: "*Why would that be necessary as opposed to just using braces by itself to delimit scope (like in C)?*" block scope is relatively very recent in JS. It did not exist for 20 years while IIFEs existed.

Comment: @VLAZ 20 years!!! I didn't realise it had taken that long.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Damn kids better get off my lawn pretty quick (I'm only giving them 5 years)!

Comment: @evolutionxbox JS was first defined in 95-ish. ES6 in 2015. So, about 20 years difference. Give or take. It would also vary depending on when you actually consider block scope to have been introduced (in the spec or major support) but 20 years is close enough.

Comment: IIFEs can be used as closures, Braces can't

Comment: @MisterJojo You can't use an IIFE as a closure, because it's executed immediately. The closure isn't saved anywhere. Maybe you meant that you can use an IIFE as an expression, e.g. `foo = function() { ... }();`

Comment: @Barmar doesn't  `foo = (function() { return 'foo'; }())` count? (since the E part of IIFE is expression)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I should have written as unique closure

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's the example I showed in my comment.

Comment: But you can get the same result with a block. Just replace `return 'foo'` with `foo = 'foo'`

Comment: @Barmar  it can also be a more complex object

Comment: @MisterJojo Of course, that was just an example. But whatever the IIFE returns, you can get the same effect by assigning it to the result variable in a block.

Comment: @Barmar not if your IIFE use some arguments

Comment: The arguments can be replaced with `let variable = value;` at the beginning of the block.

Comment: @Barmar in this case you create some  extra-scope  variables, which is not the same

Comment: @MisterJojo No you don't because they're inside the block, so they're scoped to the block.

Comment: @Barmar how can you replace `const counter = ((val=5)=>
  {
  let count = 0
  return { inc : _=> count += val
         , dec : _=> count -= val
         }
  })(7)`   with brace method ?

Comment: @MisterJojo You can't do it for a `const`, since it requires declaring outside the block then assigning inside the block. So that's an exception.

Comment: @MisterJojo What's the point of having a default value for the parameter of an IIFE? But my point about the parameter is that you can simply put `let val = 7;` at the beginning of the block in place of `((val) => ...)(7)`

Comment: @Barmar this is part of a personal code library that I use in different applications,  
the `val` can be an array `((val=[]) => ...)( myObj.someArrRef )`

Comment: Related [javascript-difference-between-using-an-iife-and-a-block-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527870/javascript-difference-between-using-an-iife-and-a-block-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript first appeared in 1995. The first specification edition was from 1997.

The specification that does include block scope is ES6 from 2015. Therefore, there has been no block scope for close to 20 years before it was introduced. IIFEs have existed in the mean time.

Also worth noting that block scope is not universal. It does work for `let` and `const` but not `var`

```js
{
  var foo = 42;
}

console.log(foo); //output: 42

(function() {
  var bar = 42;
})();

console.log(bar); // error because `bar` does not exist in this context
```

Functions are also block-scoped as of ES6 but the rules around that are *weird*.

```js
console.log("---- foo ----");

console.log("before block", foo); //output: undefined
{
  function foo() { return 42; }
}
console.log("after block", foo);  //output: function foo() { return 42; }


console.log("---- bar ----");

function bar() { return 1; }

console.log("before block", bar());   //output: 1
{
  function bar() { return 2; }
  console.log("inside block", bar()); //output: 2
}
console.log("after block ", bar());   //output: 2


console.log("---- baz ----");

{
  function baz() { return 1; }

  console.log("before inner block", baz());   //output: 1
  {
    function baz() { return 2; }
    console.log("inside inner block", baz()); //output: 2
  }
  console.log("after inner block ", baz());   //output: 1
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

Comment: thanks for this. Could you briefly comment on the parts of the block-scope that is weird (or unexpected to someone that doesn't know the rules)? Also, what are the `//1`, `//2` comments for?

Comment: `//1` and `//2` are just the output you'd get in the console. As for what is weird - for `bar()` you'd get 1, 2, 2 thus after the block the inner definition remains, however for `baz` the output is 1, 2, 1, thus after the inner block the definition from outside the inner block remains. The structure for `bar` and `baz` is the same, except `baz` is wrapped in an additional block which changes the results.

Comment: The whole point of `let` is that it's block-scoped instead of function-scoped. They didn't want to make a breaking change when they did this.